# What is the use of /<*>/ in the following script?

Tags: bash

Its a simple question but I am not able to find answer on Google.
I am new to scripting.

```
while read something
do         
 var=${something/<*>/ }       
 #perform some operation
done < $1
```

I want to know the use of /<*>/ here.
I am able to get the same result if I use

```
var=${something}
```

Any idea whats the use of /<*>/  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for "substring replacement" in the [string manipulation guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). It replaces patterns like `<stuff>` with a space.

```
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo $something
Fun on a <bun>
[cnicutar@ariel ~]$ echo ${something/<*>/ }
Fun on a
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.
Yours expansion should delete `<*>` which expands as pathname. You get same results
probably because there is no match for this pattern in your input.